# How to create a specific default list in defaultdict?

Tags: python, lambda, defaultdict

I am trying to build a defaultdict which is initialized with a specific list. Such that if I access the dict using a key that does exist, it will be initialized with a specific list, let's say `[True, True, True]`.

Instead of doing this

```
my_defaultdict = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

So, for example, something like this (obviously would not work)

```
my_defaultdict = collections.defaultdict([True, True, True])
```

I tried something like this, but this does not work

```
my_defaultdict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: list[True, True, True])
```

I looked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419401/python-defaultdict-and-lambda) for a start, but could not figure it out.

Comment: Tried `lambda: [True, True, True]`?

Comment: ugh! yes. that is correct. I thought i had tried that. Thank you!!

Comment: @doublep that needs more parentheses: `list() takes at most 1 argument`. Note that the `lambda` *also* creates a new list each time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Ugh, I just deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaultdict`'s argument should be a function or any callable object:

```
my_defaultdict = collections.defaultdict(lambda : [True,True,True])
```