# How to interpret this defaultdict() python code

Tags: python, standard-library

```
x = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```

how do you interpret this code? Initial impression is that x would be a dictionary with values calling the lambda function which creates another dictionary with values int.

Comment: This might be useful -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419401/python-defaultdict-and-lambda

Comment: You could also run it and see what happens...