# Data extraction: Creating dictionary of dictionaries with lists in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have data similar to the following in a file:

```
Name, Age, Sex, School, height, weight, id

Joe, 10, M, StThomas, 120, 20, 111

Jim, 9, M, StThomas, 126, 22, 123

Jack, 8, M, StFrancis, 110, 15, 145

Abel, 10, F, StFrancis, 128, 23, 166
```

The actual data might be 100 columns and a million rows.

What I am trying to do is create a dict in the following pattern:

```
school_data = {'StThomas': {'weight':[20,22], 'height': [120,126]},
               'StFrancis': {'weight':[15,23], 'height': [110,128]} }
```

Things I tried:

1. Trial 1: (very expensive in terms of computation)

   ```
   school_names  = []
   for lines in read_data[1:]:
       data = lines.split('\t')
       school_names.append(data[3])

   school_names = set(school_names)

   for lines in read_data[1:]:
       for school in schools:
           if school in lines:
               print lines
   ```
2. Trial 2:

   ```
   for lines in read_data[1:]:
       data = lines.split('\t')
       school_name = data[3]
       height = data[4]
       weight = data[5]
       id = data [6]
       x[id] = {school_name: (weight, height)}
   ```

The above two are methods in which I tried to proceed but did not get closer to the solution.

Comment: What are the other columns? Are they relevant for the computation or are you looking to do with those extra columns the same thing that you did with weight/height (group values by School)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this within the standard library is using existing tools, [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from csv import DictReader

data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))  # *

with open(datafile) as file_:
    for row in DictReader(file_):
        data[row[' School'].strip()]['height'].append(int(row[' height']))
        data[row[' School'].strip()]['weight'].append(int(row[' weight']))
```

Note that the spaces in e.g. `' School'` and the `.strip()` are necessary because of the spaces in the header row of your input file. Result:

```
>>> data
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10261c0c8>, {'StFrancis': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'weight': [15, 23], 'height': [110, 128]}), 'StThomas': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'weight': [20, 22], 'height': [120, 126]})})
>>> data['StThomas']['height']
[120, 126]
```

Alternatively, if you're planning to do further analysis, look into something like [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and its `DataFrame` data structure.

* *see [Python defaultdict and lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8419401/3001761) if this seems weird*

Comment: Works great! Thanks