# defaultdict with a default value that is a lambda that takes a parameter produces error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use defaultdict to store several lambdas that take one param, but to respond with a default lambda with the key is missing. I get an error when trying to use the default:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda str: str)
d['a'] = lambda str: f"aaa{str}"

d['a']('hello')
>>> 'aaahello'
d['b']('hello')
>>> <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'str'
```

Comment: The parameter to `defaultdict()` isn't the default value, it's a callable object (that will receive no parameters) that must return the default value.  (If it didn't work this way, you couldn't create a defaultdict with a mutable default value such as a list.)  Try `defaultdict(lambda: (lambda str: str))` - except that you shouldn't be using the built-in name `str` here, that's just going to cause confusion.

Comment: Possibly a helpful thread for your request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419401/python-defaultdict-and-lambda

Comment: @jasonharper that makes sense and fixed it.  You should submit as an answer. BTW not sure what you mean by str, are you referring to the str() function?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your default lamba is intended to just bounce the called string back to the callee. As jasonharper mentioned, `defaultdict` only takes a callable function with no parameters, but using `str` as the name of the argument to lambda *shadows* the built-in `str()` function.

I suggest using `defaultdict(lambda : str)` because this lambda doesn't need any arguments. This is what it would look like:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda : str)
d['b']('hello')
>>> 'hello'
```