# defaultdict with a lambda that uses the key as a parameter

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, parameters

I was trying to create a defaultdict where the key was used as a parameter to create a classed object, but I get a TypeError when I try.  I've put a minimum example below

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Intersection:
    def __init__(self,xy):
        self.position = xy
        self.stuff = []
    def add(self,stuff):
        self.stuff.append(stuff)

intersections: defaultdict[tuple[int,int],Intersection] = defaultdict(lambda xy: Intersection(xy))
intersections[(1,2)].add('stuff')
>>> TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xy'
```

I googled the error and it came up with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57720100/defaultdict-with-a-default-value-that-is-a-lambda-that-takes-a-parameter-produce) which is close to what I'm trying to do but just far enough not to be able to answer how to do this

Comment: Yes that is indeed a duplicate, though that question didn't come up when I searched the error I got, nor when I searched various combinations of 'python' 'defaultdict' 'lambda' and 'key' so I included all of these in my question which should help boost visibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching around for a while I stumbled upon [this github issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/82496) asking about this functionality.  It seems this will not be added to defaultdict but it CAN be done using the `__missing__()` method on dict.

Since this was difficult for me to find I wanted to post it somewhere where other people (including future me) can find it.

```
class Intersection:
    def __init__(self,xy):
        self.position = xy
        self.stuff = []
    def add(self,stuff):
        self.stuff.append(stuff)

class KeyDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self,key):
        self[key] = Intersection(key)
        return self[key]

intersections = KeyDict()
intersections[(1,2)].add('stuff')
print(intersections)
>>> {(1, 2): <__main__.Intersection object at 0x000001A3226E0F70>}
```

Note: This works with [parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745952/how-to-expand-a-list-to-function-arguments-in-python) too.  Originally I had it included but I factored it out for clarity